# PHP - Proper way to extend class

Tags: php, oop, class, extend

I am currently working on a mini 'framework' and I am having some difficulties. I'm attempting this in order to strengthen my understanding of basic concepts utilized in most MVC's (At least from what I have seen). So yes, I do understand that using a framework may be easier and not everything that I am doing is ideal. I am just trying to learn more.

So I have 2 files that I am currently working with.

FrontController.php

```
<?php   
class FrontController {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->go(); // RUNS GO FUNCTION UPON LOADING
    }

    public function go() {          
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // GRABS URL
        $action = explode("/", $url); // SPLITS UP URL INTO SECTIONS

        $object = ucfirst($action[2]) . "Controller"; // SETS 2ND SECTION OF URL TO UPPERCASE AND IDENTIFIES THE CONTROLLER
        $file = APP_DIR . "/" . $object . ".php"; // IDENTIFIES THE FILE THAT WILL BE USED

        if(!is_file($file)){ // DETERMINES IF FILE EXISTS
            $this->fail(); // IF NOT, FAILS
        } else {
            require_once $file; // IF EXISTS, PULLS IT IN
            $method = ucfirst($action[3]); // THE 3RD SECTION OF THE URL IS THE METHOD
            $controller = new $object(); // CREATE INSTANCE OF THE IDENTIFIED OBJECT

            if(!method_exists($controller, $method)){ // DETERMINES IF METHOD EXISTS IN THE CLASS
                $this->fail(); // IF NOT, FAILS
            }

            $controller->$method(); // RUN METHOD
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    public function fail() {
        echo "<h1>Failure</h1>"; // FAILURE MESSAGE
    }
}
```

/application/BaseController.php

```
<?php   
class BaseController {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->session();
    }

    public function session() {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = 1;
        echo "hi";
    }
}
```

So what I would like to be able to do is extend the BaseController with the FrontController. I figured that extending the BaseController would allow me to add common functionality to my entire application. The problem is that I am not certain how to do this properly. I know that I need to 'require' BaseController.php into FrontController.php somehow, but I have seen many different ways and I want to know which is most correct.

What I have tried is simply adding 'require_once("/application/BaseController.php");' to the top of FrontController.php and then extending the FrontController class, but this isn't working (blank page), and from what I have read, it is not the best way.

I read into __autoload() but I do not understand how to use it effectively. Do I just put this at the top of my FrontController.php file and extend my class after that?

So, to summarize, I would like to extend my FrontController class (and other future classes, when necessary) with my BaseController. I would just like some advice for how to accomplish this task effectively. It may even be possible that the way I have this thought out is ass backwards, and if that is the case, please let me know!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend classes like:

```
<?php
class FrontController extends BaseController {
 ..code...
}


?>
```

__autoload is a magic method which loads classes automatically. So you could add this in your FrontController as an example and load your controllers as needed. Read about autoloading classes here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Also, take advantage of SPL in PHP which will help define your application better.

Comment: So this would go outside of the actual class in the FrontController.php file? Wouldn't that make it kind of useless for my needs? It would only be used for this single instance. I'm not sure how to implement it so that it may be reused.

Comment: Whatever class is handling the routing, you'd add the autoload there. Your go method seems to be doing this already though. __autoload is merely a helper method, much like _set and _get. They automate issues that developers used to deal with manually over the years.

Comment: I'd review a framework like CodeIgniter and see how they handle loading classes.

Comment: I should also note, often frameworks use a loading class, which your controllers initiate. Then all subclasses have access to that loading class to use as well.

Comment: I suppose this answers my question but I still feel as if some things are left unknown for me. This is nothing you can help, I appreciate your effort. Thank you.

Comment: Theres no 1 way to build this stuff, there are only patterns and best practices. Sometimes a simple little solution without big overhead is better. But in this case, maybe a separate loading mechanism makes sense. Otherwise, the above answer is how you extend classes.

Answer (score 1):

To give a better structure on your framework and your future project I recommend you to use some tricks and best practices.

- Namespacing: for better organizing your code and your classes
- Autoloading: for autoloading your classes in a smart way

Namespacing http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php and autoloading http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php can be viewed on official documentation.

To better understanding you can take a look here

1. Define and register autoloading function

   ```
   function autoload($class) {
       preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', ltrim( $class, '\\' ), $match ) );
       require str_replace( '\\', '/', $match[ 1 ] ). str_replace( [ '\\', '_' ], '/', $match[ 2 ] ). '.php';
   }

   spl_autoload_register('autoload');
   ```
2. Use namespacing around your application

Base Controller

```
    <?php namespace App\Controller;

    class BaseController { ... }
```

FrontController

```
    <?php namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\BaseController as BaseController;

    class FrontController extends BaseController { ... }
```